# var dump not working for a particular php file

Tags: php

I have a `login.html` in which the `form` is defined as follows:

```
<form method="post" action= "do_authorize.php"  name="lform">
  <span class="style1">First Initial Plus Last Name :</span>  
    <input type="text" name="user" size="25">
    <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

My `do_authorize` is as follows:

```
<?
session_start();

require('../databaseConnectionFileFolder/dbconnection.php');

$user             = $_POST["user"]; 

var_dump($user);

$_SESSION['username']=$user;

var_dump($user);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $table_name_users WHERE username = \"$user\"";

var_dump($sql);

$result=@mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die("couldn't execute query");

$num=mysql_numrows($result);
if ($num != 0) {

/*$cookie_name="$user";
$cookie_value="ok";
$cookie_expire=time()+86400;
$cookie_domain=".columbia.edu";

setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_expire, "/", $cookie_domain, 0);
*/
    print "<script>";
    print "self.location='somethingelse.php';";
    print "</script>";

} else {
echo "<p>you're not authorized";
}


?>
```

I have included `var_dump($user);` and `var_dump($sql);` at appropriate places and it doesn't seem to print the user value and sql. All it prints every time on the browser is the following:

```
"; print "self.location='somethingelse.php';"; print ""; } else { echo "
you're not authorized"; } ?>
```

I was referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939362/php-refuses-to-output-data-from-var-dump-print-etc) and I did the sanity check as mentioned in the following comment by  `Dan Nissenbaum` and it works for me:

```
For sanity checking, does the same problem occur in an independent .php file in the same webroot - something simple like <?php $x = array(1,2,3); var_dump($x); ?>?
```

Comment: Try `<?php` instead of just `<?`. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: That worked, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write your php code inside

```
<?php //code ?>
```

instead of

```
<? //code ?>
```

And i guess a better alternative to print data is `echo`. Not `print`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, let's enable showing errors, notices, etc.:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This way, if any notice is being emmited by PHP, you'll know.

Now, try this:

```
ob_start();  
var_dump($user);  
$out = ob_get_clean();  
echo $out;
```

And tell us if it works.

Good Luck.

Comment: Showing Errors was enabled.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I tried `<?php instead of just <?` as someone mentioned in the comment above and it worked